# Encapsulate menuItem with taglib, jsp, JS?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, taglib

How could I encapsulate the authentication logic, the URL and the label of a Menu item when I make use of e.g. a Dojo MenuItem widget?

What I currently have is this:

```
<auth:isRole  role="admin">
  <div dojoType="widget.Menu.MenuItem">
    <a href="<html:rewrite page="... complicated url ..."/>">
      <bean:message key="label.goes.here"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</auth:isRole>
```

And what I would like to achieve would be something like:

```
<util:menuitem role="admin" link="...complicated url..." label="label.goes.here" />
```

Is this possible to implement with a custom tag?
Would there be other options to use Ajax or JS helpers?

Comment: not sure how I can quote html tags here without having them interpreted by SO

Comment: Markdown's markup rules can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a project called [Struts Menu](http://struts-menu.sourceforge.net/) that is a combination of a taglib, a config file, and Velocity templates to encapsulate menu display logic and security.  I don't think there's an existing Velocity template for Dojo menus, but it shouldn't be difficult to write one.

Answer (score 1):

It most certainly is possible with a custom tag but including other tags in a custom tag can be ornery. [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) is a good alternative to JSP that has actually replaced it in the J2EE spec for J2EE6. It allows you to create custom tags via other components. Check out [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/) as it is a good tutorial.